# Equation of the form $\mathbf{\Phi}'(t)=\mathbf A(t)\mathbf{\Phi}(t)$.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Let $\mathbf{\Phi}(t)$ and $\mathbf A(t)$ be matrices satisfying the differential equation
$$
\mathbf{\Phi}'(t)=\mathbf A(t)\mathbf{\Phi}(t)\ .
$$
If I am not mistaken, if $\mathbf A$ and its integral commutes, i.e.

> $$
> \mathbf A(t) \cdot \int_0^t \mathbf A(\tau)d\tau = \int_0^t \mathbf A(\tau)d\tau \ \cdot \mathbf A(t)\ ,
> $$

then $\mathbf \Phi(t)$ can be written in the form
$$\mathbf \Phi(t)=\exp\left( \int_0^t \mathbf A(\tau)d\tau \right)\ .$$

Evidently, such condition is satisfied when $\mathbf A$ is a symmetric (or Hermitian). I want to know if there's a similar theory when the highlighted condition is not satisfied.

In particular, I am interested in the case where $\mathbf A(t)$ is anti Hermitian and $\int_0^t \mathbf A(\tau)d\tau  $ is Hermitian. Any help or references would be highly appreciated.

**Edit**: As some users had mentioned, some of my claims might be incorrect. I must apologize for that. Let me summarize my question to avoid misinterpreting and confusion

> Is there a general method to find $\mathbf \Phi(t)$ when $A(t)$ and $B(t)=\int_0^t A(\tau) d\tau$ do not commute?

Comment: Is this case even possible?

Comment: what is $\frac{d}{dt} (\int_0^t A(\tau) d \tau)^k$ ? what is $\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}  (\int_0^t A(\tau) d \tau)^k$ ?

Comment: @Did You mean the case Hermitian vs. Anti-Hermitian? I am not so sure myself. The question was given to me by a friend in that form. Well, he might have made some mistake...

Comment: (there is a trap. did you find the derivative of $(\int_0^t A(\tau) d\tau)^k$ ?? )

Comment: @user1952009 I must admit that I am, for most part, ignorant of any basic result in matrix differential equation and dynamical system in general. Please bare with my stupidity but I cannot understand you hint at all.

Comment: I meant checking if it is true that $\Phi(t) = \exp(\int_0^t A(\tau) d \tau)$ is solution. The problem is that in general $A(t)$ doesn't commute with $B(t) = \int_0^t A(\tau) d \tau$, and in that case  $\frac{d}{dt} B(t)^k =  \sum_{m=1}^k B(t)^m \frac{d B(t)}{dt} B(t)^{k-1-m} = \sum_{m=1}^k B(t)^m  A(t) B(t)^{k-1-m}$, so that $\Phi(t) = \exp(B(t)) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B(t)^k}{k!}$, and $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{m=1}^k B(t)^m \frac{d B(t)}{dt} B(t)^{k-1-m}  = $\ldots$.

Comment: Now if $A(t)$ commutes with $B(t)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices for example if $A(t) = P D(t) P^{-1}$ and $B(t) = P \Lambda(t) P^{-1}$ with $D(t),\Lambda(t)$ diagonal, then everything becomes easy

Comment: @user1952009 Maybe I didn't make it clear enough in the OP. My question can be summarized as "Is there a general method to find $\mathbf \Phi(t)$ when $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ do not commute?".

Comment: I don't know how to build a general method ( see Qiaochu answer), but what I wrote (the derivative of $\exp(B(t))$ which is not $B'(t) \exp(B(t))$) is enough for seeing it can be quite complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential works under the very strong hypothesis that all of the $A(t), t \in \mathbb{R}$ commute. I am not aware of a weaker general hypothesis than this.

Otherwise, the solution can be expressed as a [Dyson series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series) or a [Magnus series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion). The former is common in physics, and more specifically in [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory). The latter is arguably better, though (e.g. if the $A(t)$ lie in some Lie algebra then so do the terms of the Magnus series).