# A differential equation involving the cross product

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

In the course of work in atomic physics, I've run into a differential equation of the form $$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{X}(t) = \vec{\Omega}(t) \times \vec{X}(t)$$ where $\vec{\Omega}(t)$ is given and we wish to solve for $\vec{X}(t)$.  Is there a name for this type of equation?  Can you please provide references on the structure of solutions to this equation?

Comment: So $\Omega(t)$ is your "instantaneous rotation vector". Looks like the general solution is any curve with unit speed on the sphere.

Comment: @JeanMarie To clarify: $\vec{\Omega}$ is part of the problem data.  I have edited the question to make this explicit.  It is true that any curve on the sphere is a solution for some choice of $\vec{\Omega}$, but that's not quite what this problem asks.

Comment: If you are used to Serret-Frenet mobile frame: $\Omega(t)$ is directing the binormal.

Comment: @JeanMarie That's useful, and I was not aware of that name.  Thank you!

Comment: For discussions of numerical methods see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816717/equation-of-the-form-mathbf-phit-mathbf-at-mathbf-phit, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36578/special-case-runge-kutta-methods-to-exploit-structure-in-linear-ode, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642729, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556083/solving-matrix-differential-equation-enforcing-orthogonality, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416185/interesting-odes-on-lie-groups

Answer (score 1):

In classical dynamics, this kind of equation is associated with the [kinematic transport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame) (not to be confused with the continuum mechanical transport theorem).

The general form is an identity that describes the rate of change of a vector quantity $\vec{X}(t)$ in time as measured in an inertial reference frame $A$—let's call that $\frac{d\vec{X}(t)_A}{dt}$—as compared to the rate of change of the quantity in a rotating reference frame $B$, $\frac{d\vec{X}(t)_B}{dt}$. The general form is:

$$\frac{d\vec{X}(t)_A}{dt} = \frac{d\vec{X}(t)_B}{dt} + \vec{\Omega}(t)\times\vec{X}(t)$$

where $\vec{\Omega}(t)$ is the angular velocity of frame $B$ with respect to $A$. When the quantity you are considering is not changing in the rotating frame, it simplifies to the form you have above. Most textbooks on dynamics contain a discussion of this equation—see, for example, see Chapter 18 of [Ruina's text](http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/Book/RuinaPratap-July-12-2019.pdf).